# Java nio partial read

Tags: java, client-server, nio, partial, bytebuffer

My goal is to send different kind of messages from client to server, and it will be text based. The thing I am uncertain of is how to del with partial reads here. I will have to be sure that I get a whole message and nothing more.

Do anyone have experience with that?

Here is what I have so far:

```
    private void handleNewClientMessage(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    SocketChannel sendingChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

    ByteBuffer receivingBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);
    int bytesRead = sendingChannel.read(receivingBuffer);
    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        receivingBuffer.flip();

        byte[] array = new byte[receivingBuffer.limit()];
        receivingBuffer.get(array);
        String message = new String(array);

        System.out.println("Server received "  +message);           
    }
    selector.wakeup();
}
```

But I have no way of "ending" the message and be certain to have one full message.

Best regards,
O

Comment: You should add your text protocol on top of socket. Like HTTP.

Comment: Hi @Nikolai . That sounds nice, do you have a link to some example here? Cheers!

Comment: HTTP is actual example. You can use HttpComponents library to parse HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can never be sure you won't read more than one message unless you only read one byte at a time. (Which I don't suggest).

Instead I would read as much as you can into a ByteBuffer and then parse it to find the end of the message e.g. a newline for text.

When you find the end of a line extract it and convert it to a String and process it.  repeat until you have a partial message (or nothing left)

If you find you have only part of a message, you compact() (if position() > 0) when you have and try to read() some more.

This will allows you to read as many messages at once as you can but can also handle incomplete messages.

Note: You will need to keep the ByteBuffer for a connection so you know what partial messages you have read before.

Note: this is will not work if you have a message which is larger than your buffer size.  I suggest using a recycled direct ByteBuffer of say 1+ MB. With direct ByteBuffers only the pages of the ByteBuffer which are used get allocated to real memory.

If you are concerned about performance I would re-use your `byte[]` where possible.  You only need to re-allocate it if you need more space than you have already.

BTW, You might find using a BufferedReader with Plain IO is much simpler to use, but still performance well enough.

Comment: Hi @Peter_Lawrey , thanks for a good explanation. I'll try to implement this approach.